# Retrieve data via an external API on Drupal 9

Tags: api, guzzle, drupal-9

I'm using drupal 9 and I want get some data from external API, I searched for solutions. One solution is using guzzlehttp library, and all the sites say make guzzlehttp request with some codes, but none of them said where the code should be added! please help me, I don't know what to do? If there are better solutions, please guide me.
Thanks...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom module or use an existing one to add your code, if you want to fetch data in controller then add this code in you controller function or else you can add in your .module file for testing. Here is an example to retrieve data from an external API in Drupal 9, 10

```
function FUNCTION_NAME() {
  $url = 'https://api.example.com/data';
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($url);
  $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), TRUE);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Now I can get the data by a custom module inside a test page, but I don't know how to use it where I want. Currently I have created a custom block and it is showing me statistics as static numbers by html codes, I want these numbers not to be static and to be received from the same API.
I don't know how to do this, can you help me?

Comment: I want to use the data in home page.

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle already added inside composer, runs by default.

Now, how you want to call another rest-api?

Through controller, Restful API or service, so above function works, or else give more expected functionality.